# React app / Chrome Dev Tools strange output: "in Startnull" - main.js: 42

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

When I launch my React application I have a strange output in the console, and I am really curious about it:

[image: in Startnull]

I think i could probably be missing a parameter referencing the version of the app, just need some Stackoverflow clarity. Here is my main.js where you can see the issue (line 42):

[image: main.js]

Thank you!

Comment: Version argument is null and by concatenating console log message with it, you see a complete string, try to run in console "my text"+null and you will observe the same result. If you want to see messages as being separate, you should do something like console.log("my message ", variable)

Comment: How should i properly set up setup version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the Katalon Recorder Chrome Extension. If you hover over main.js tab you'll be able to see the location of the file.

Comment: Indeed. This is exactly what is happening. Thank you @szaske.